# How to extract the file name without folder path with GetFullPathName

Tags: c, winapi, filenames

I want to extract the file name from path string but i have difficulties with the GetFullPathName Function:

```
WCHAR *fileExt;
WCHAR szDir[256]; //dummy buffer
GetFullPathNameW(g_fileName,256, szDir,&fileExt); //g_filename is filename with path string
swprintf(szDestDir, L"C:\\Example\\%s", fileExt);
MessageBoxW(hwnd,szDestDir,L"Debug",MB_OK); //debug message
```

every time the message box displays "C:\Example\0" with 0 instead a filename, for example "text.txt".

Comment: What's the Contents of g_fileName in your test case?

Comment: The code works. Does your szDestDir have enough space to hold the output?

Comment: g_fileName is an LPCWSTR from an open file dialog, and szDestDir have 256 chars allocated.

Comment: Make sure to double check everything. The following program works: http://pastebin.com/rWbhAwxn

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code a little bit for simplicity:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char *fileExt;
    char szDir[256]; //dummy buffer
    GetFullPathName(argv[0], 256, szDir, &fileExt); 
    printf("Full path: %s\nFilename: %s", szDir, fileExt);
    return 0;
}
```

And ran it on its own source code, with the following results:

```
C:\C\source>trash9 trash9.cpp
Full path: C:\C\source\trash9
Filename: trash9
```

That said, I have to wonder why you'd mess with `GetFullPathName` at all. In the comments you say you're getting the file name `GetOpenFileName`. This means you're getting the file information in an `OPENFILENAME` structure. This includes both `lpstrFile`, which has the full path to the file, and `lpstrFileTitle` which has the file name without path information -- exactly what you seem to want.