# Why I can't get directory name

Tags: c, winapi

My program, where I work with Win API:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int _main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    char *fileExt = NULL;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(argv[0], MAX_PATH, szDir, &fileExt);
    printf("Full path: %s\nFilename: %s\n", szDir, fileExt);

    return 0;
}
```

I use example from [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?118078-GetFullPathName) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632117/how-to-extract-the-file-name-without-folder-path-with-getfullpathname), but I've got an error message: Argument of type “char *” is incompatible with parameter of type “LPWSTR”.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: you are mixing up ANSI and UNICODE, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc) explains the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string defined as below is called an ANSI string.

```
char* fileExt = NULL;
```

And a string defined as below can be an ANSI string or a Unicode string. Your project is compiled with the `UNICODE/_UNICODE` macro, so it is a Unicode string.

```
TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
```

You can't mix them together, for an introduction to the data type identifiers in VC++ like `TCHAR` and `LPCTSTR`, please refer to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc).

I made several modifications to your code, as following.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR *fileExt = NULL; 
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(argv[0], MAX_PATH, szDir, &fileExt);
    _tprintf(_T("Full path: %s\nFilename: %s\n"), szDir, fileExt); 
    return 0;
}
```